# android room insert complicated object self Referencing Table

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have complicated object that I need to find a good way to save
I have a `Message` object who holds List of `Attachments`
each `Attachment` can hold another List of `Attachments` ...[OMG, TTI know]
So I thought maybe I should do something like that:
I will give each of the `Attachments` - `messageId` and `parentAttachmentId`
when the parent is null that means Its belong to the list of the message itself
and when the id belongs to another attachments that means it belong to his list

So, I think I should get all attachments belongs to message Y,
then iterate over the list and some how sort it correctly I get and check which one belongs to who
and then sort in the correct order

but maybe their is a way with room to do it more easily

Message:
val messageId: String,
val message:String,
val attachments: List

Attachment
val attachmentId
....

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have to port an existing app using Room instead of directly working with SQLite classes. I have Object{Id: Int, ParentId: Int?... List<Object> Children}. I get the data tree by Retrofit and have to save it for offline usage...